# Jinja2 - display delete button in particular html table row if condition is true

Tags: python, html, django, jinja2

I'm trying to create an if else condition using jinja2 where only table row with the status `pending_approval` or `scheduled` will display a delete button beside it. But I'm having trouble figuring it out because all the data in the table is displayed in a `for loop` so if the condition is true and all row have the delete button and vice versa.

Any help is much appreciated

Below is my code :

model.py

```
class Leave(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+')
    type = models.ForeignKey(LeavesType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+')
    status = (('cancelled', 'Cancelled'),
              ('taken', 'Taken'),
              ('pending_approval', 'Pending Approval'),
              ('scheduled', 'Scheduled'),
              ('weekend', 'Week End'),
              ('public_holiday', 'Public holiday'),
              )
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=status, default='pending_approval')
```

view.py

```
def my_leaves_view(request):
     leaves_log = Leave.objects.all().filter(employee=request.user.profile.employee.id)
     context = {'leaves_log': leaves_log}
     return render(request, 'hrm/employee/details/my_leaves.html', context)
```

html

```
<table id="Log" class="display table table-hover table-responsive leaves-table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="small text-muted text-uppercase"><strong>Leave Type</strong></th>
        <th class="small text-muted text-uppercase"><strong>Status</strong></th>
        <th class="small text-muted text-uppercase"><strong></strong></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{% for field in leaves_log %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{field.type}}</td>
        <td><img class="media-object img-circle status-icon-size" src="/media/dashboard/ui/file_status/{{field.status}}.png" style="display: inline-block; height: 24px; margin-right: 10px;">{{field.status}}</td>
        <td><div class="btn-group">
            {% if field.status == 'pending_approval' or 'scheduled'%}
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs dropdown-toggle active" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Action <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                    <li onclick="delete_leaves();">
                        <a href="/hrm/employee/{{field.id}}/delete/" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');">
                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-trash text-gray-lighter m-r-1"></i>Withdraw
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </td>
        {% else %}
        <td></td>
        {% endif %}
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the `or` operator correctly. It is used to separate two boolean values, so you can imagine

```
{% if field.status == 'pending_approval' or 'scheduled' %}
```

being interpreted as

```
{% if bool(field.status == 'pending_approval') or bool('scheduled') %}
```

and `bool('any non-empty string')` is always `True`

The correct syntax is

```
{% if field.status == 'pending_approval' or field.status == 'scheduled' %}
```

or

```
{% if field.status in ['pending_approval', 'scheduled'] %}
```